# After adding sliding menu to applications code, the app crashes, the application works in landscape mode

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer, slidingmenu

Here is my MainActivity. After entering IP address the app captures the desktop screen and it goes into landscape mode. I tried to add sliding menu to add some functionalities but the app unfortunately stops working. How can I add the internet connection information module to this existing code?

```
package info.androidhive.slidingmenu;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.method.KeyListener;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class TransmissionActivity extends Activity {

    private Socket client, client1;
    private EditText textField, textField1, keyboard;
    private ObjectOutputStream oos; // serialize java objects and primitive data
                                    // types
    float point[];
    private Button button;
    private ImageView imv;
    boolean flag = false, flag1 = false;
    int size = 0, frequency = 300;
    private Thread t; // concurrent unit of execution
    private static InputMethodManager imm; // manages interactions among all
                                            // interfaces

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_transmission);
        imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

        textField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1); // reference to the
                                                                // text field
        textField1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.frequency); // reference to
                                                                // the text
                                                                // field
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1); // reference to the send
                                                        // button
        keyboard = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.keyboard); // reference to the
                                                            // clavier
        imv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1); // reference to the
                                                            // image view

        keyboard.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0); // shows
                                                                        // keyboard

            }
        });

        keyboard.setKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onKeyUp(View view, Editable text, int keyCode,
                    KeyEvent event) {

                return false;
            }

            // when the user presses the key
            @Override
            public boolean onKeyOther(View view, Editable text, KeyEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onKeyDown(View view, Editable text, int keyCode,
                    KeyEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // sendCoordinate(event.getDisplayLabel());
                // Toast.makeText(TransmissionActivity.this,
                // "keycode:'"+keyCode+"' label: '"+event.getDisplayLabel()+"'",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if ((keyCode == event.KEYCODE_SPACE)
                        || (keyCode >= event.KEYCODE_0 && keyCode <= event.KEYCODE_9)
                        || (keyCode >= event.KEYCODE_A && keyCode <= event.KEYCODE_Z)) {
                    sendCoordinate((int) event.getDisplayLabel());
                } else if (keyCode == 67) {
                    sendCoordinate(0);
                }
                // else if(keyCode==event.KEYCODE_ENTER){
                // sendCoordinate((int) -2);
                // }
                //
                // else if(keyCode==event.KEYCODE_APOSTROPHE){
                // sendCoordinate((int) -3);
                // }
                // else if(keyCode==event.KEYCODE_MINUS){
                // sendCoordinate((int) -4);
                // }
                //
                // else if(keyCode==event.KEYCODE_SEMICOLON){
                // sendCoordinate((int) -5);
                // }
                //
                // else if(keyCode==event.KEYCODE_SLASH){
                // sendCoordinate((int) -6);
                // }
                //
                // else if(keyCode==event.KEYCODE_SPACE){
                // sendCoordinate((int) -7);
                // }
                //
                // else if(keyCode==event.KEYCODE_PERIOD){
                // sendCoordinate((int) -8);
                // }
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public int getInputType() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public void clearMetaKeyState(View view, Editable content,
                    int states) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        imv.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (flag) {
                    if (!flag1) {
                        sendCoordinate(event.getX(), event.getY());
                        flag1 = true;
                    } else {
                        flag1 = false;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
        textField.setText("192.168.1.3");
        textField1.setText("" + frequency);
        button.setText("Start");
        // Button press event listener

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    // AdBuddiz.showAd(TransmissionActivity.this);
                    if (!flag) {
                        flag = true;
                        button.setText("Stop");
                        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
                        EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                        ll.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        et.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                charge();

                            }
                        });
                        t.start();
                    } else {
                        flag = false;
                        button.setText("Start");
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });

    }

    final Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            opt.inDither = true;
            opt.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
            // textField.setText(msg.getData().getInt("2"));
            imv.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(msg.getData()
                    .getByteArray("1"), 0,
                    msg.getData().getByteArray("1").length, opt));

        }
    };

    public void charge() {
        while (flag) {

            try {
                String ip = textField.getText().toString();
                frequency = Integer.parseInt(textField1.getText().toString());

                client = new Socket(ip, 9999); // connect to server
                // printwriter = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(),true);
                // printwriter.write(messsage); //write the message to output
                // stream
                //
                // printwriter.flush();
                // printwriter.close();

                try {
                    size = 0;
                    int tailleTaille = client.getInputStream().read();
                    while (tailleTaille > 0) {
                        tailleTaille--;
                        size += client.getInputStream().read()
                                * Math.pow(256, tailleTaille);

                    }

                    Thread.sleep(frequency);

                    // client = new Socket(ip, 9999); //connect to server

                    // textField.setText(taille);
                    receiveFile(client.getInputStream());

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }

            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }

    public void receiveFile(InputStream is) throws Exception {

        byte[] imageByteArray = getImageByteArray(is);
        Message msg = handler.obtainMessage();

        Bundle data = new Bundle();

        data.putByteArray("1", imageByteArray);
        // data.putInt("2", taille);

        msg.setData(data);
        // Envoi du message au handler
        handler.sendMessage(msg);

        // int filesize = 6022386;
        // String baseDir =
        // Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        // String fileInES = baseDir + File.separator + fileName;
        // int bytesRead, current = 0;
        // byte[] mybytearray = new byte[filesize];
        // FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileInES); // destination
        // // path and
        // // name of
        // // file
        // BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        // bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
        // current = bytesRead;
        //
        // do {
        // bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray, current,
        // (mybytearray.length - current));
        // if (bytesRead >= 0)
        // current += bytesRead;
        // } while (bytesRead > -1);
        //
        // bos.write(mybytearray, 0, current);
        // bos.flush();
        // // long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        // // System.out.println(end - start);
        // bos.close();
        //
        // Bitmap bmp = null;
        // FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileInES);
        // try
        // {
        // bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
        // return bmp;
        // }
        // finally
        // {
        // fis.close();
        // }

    }

    private byte[] getImageByteArray(InputStream is) {
        // Vector<byte[]> vect = new Vector<byte[]>();

        byte[] buf = new byte[size];
        // int i=0;
        try {
            // is.mark(TAILLE_MAX);
            // while(is.read()!=-1){
            // // vect.add(buf);
            // // buf = new byte[1];
            // // textField.setText("lecture1..."+i);
            // i++;
            // }

            // is.reset();
            is.read(buf);

            // textField.setText("dernier "+buf[buf.length-1]+"  "+buf.length);
            // buf = new byte[vect.size()];
            // i=0;
            // for(byte[] byt: vect){
            // buf[i] = byt[0];
            // i++;
            // textField.setText("lecture2..."+i);
            //
            // }

            return buf;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private Thread t2;
    static String ip = "";

    public void sendCoordinate(final float x, final float y) {
        ip = textField.getText().toString();
        t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    client1 = new Socket(ip, 9998);
                    point = new float[4];
                    point[0] = x;
                    point[1] = y;
                    point[2] = imv.getWidth();
                    point[3] = imv.getHeight();
                    oos = new ObjectOutputStream(client1.getOutputStream());
                    oos.writeObject(point);
                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Agenerated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        t2.start();

    }

    public void sendCoordinate(final int c) {
        ip = textField.getText().toString();
        t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    client1 = new Socket(ip, 9998);
                    point = new float[1];
                    point[0] = c;
                    oos = new ObjectOutputStream(client1.getOutputStream());
                    oos.writeObject(point);
                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        t2.start();

    }

}

// and xml




<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >



        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.13"
            android:text="Start" >
        </Button>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/keyboard"
            android:layout_width="66dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/images"
            android:ems="10" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="" >
        </TextView>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/frequency"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.35"
            android:inputType="number" >
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" >

        <requestFocus>
        </requestFocus>
    </EditText>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
    </ImageView>

</LinearLayout>
```

// my logcat

```
09-22 20:58:34.327: D/ActivityThread(20422): handleBindApplication:info.androidhive.slidingmenu
09-22 20:58:34.347: W/ApplicationPackageManager(20422): getCSCPackageItemText()
09-22 20:58:34.347: D/DisplayManager(20422): DisplayManager()
09-22 20:58:34.517: D/OpenGLRenderer(20422): Enabling debug mode 0
09-22 20:58:34.647: I/Timeline(20422): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@41e31568 time:47987069
09-22 20:58:36.379: D/AndroidRuntime(20422): Shutting down VM
09-22 20:58:36.379: W/dalvikvm(20422): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416afbc0)
09-22 20:58:36.389: E/AndroidRuntime(20422): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-22 20:58:36.389: E/AndroidRuntime(20422): Process: info.androidhive.slidingmenu, PID: 20422
09-22 20:58:36.389: E/AndroidRuntime(20422): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-22 20:58:36.389: E/AndroidRuntime(20422):    at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:77)
09-22 20:58:36.389: E/AndroidRuntime(20422):    at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:3957)
09-22 20:58:36.389: E/AndroidRuntime(20422):    at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.HomeFragment$1.onClick(HomeFragment.java:28)
09-22 20:58:36.389: E/AndroidRuntime(20422):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4496)
09-22 20:58:36.389: E/AndroidRuntime(20422):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18603)
09-22 20:58:36.389: E/AndroidRuntime(20422):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
09-22 20:58:36.389: E/AndroidRuntime(20422):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
09-22 20:58:36.389: E/AndroidRuntime(20422):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
09-22 20:58:36.389: E/AndroidRuntime(20422):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5433)
09-22 20:58:36.389: E/AndroidRuntime(20422):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-22 20:58:36.389: E/AndroidRuntime(20422):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-22 20:58:36.389: E/AndroidRuntime(20422):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
09-22 20:58:36.389: E/AndroidRuntime(20422):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
09-22 20:58:36.389: E/AndroidRuntime(20422):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-22 20:58:39.572: I/Process(20422): Sending signal. PID: 20422 SIG: 9
09-22 20:58:55.067: D/ActivityThread(20542): handleBindApplication:info.androidhive.slidingmenu
09-22 20:58:55.087: W/ApplicationPackageManager(20542): getCSCPackageItemText()
09-22 20:58:55.087: D/DisplayManager(20542): DisplayManager()
09-22 20:58:55.207: D/OpenGLRenderer(20542): Enabling debug mode 0
09-22 20:58:55.297: I/Timeline(20542): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@41e35178 time:48007711
09-22 20:59:13.065: D/AndroidRuntime(20542): Shutting down VM
09-22 20:59:13.065: W/dalvikvm(20542): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416afbc0)
09-22 20:59:13.065: E/AndroidRuntime(20542): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-22 20:59:13.065: E/AndroidRuntime(20542): Process: info.androidhive.slidingmenu, PID: 20542
09-22 20:59:13.065: E/AndroidRuntime(20542): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-22 20:59:13.065: E/AndroidRuntime(20542):    at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:77)
09-22 20:59:13.065: E/AndroidRuntime(20542):    at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:3957)
09-22 20:59:13.065: E/AndroidRuntime(20542):    at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.HomeFragment$1.onClick(HomeFragment.java:28)
09-22 20:59:13.065: E/AndroidRuntime(20542):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4496)
09-22 20:59:13.065: E/AndroidRuntime(20542):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18603)
09-22 20:59:13.065: E/AndroidRuntime(20542):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
09-22 20:59:13.065: E/AndroidRuntime(20542):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
09-22 20:59:13.065: E/AndroidRuntime(20542):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
09-22 20:59:13.065: E/AndroidRuntime(20542):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5433)
09-22 20:59:13.065: E/AndroidRuntime(20542):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-22 20:59:13.065: E/AndroidRuntime(20542):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-22 20:59:13.065: E/AndroidRuntime(20542):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
09-22 20:59:13.065: E/AndroidRuntime(20542):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
09-22 20:59:13.065: E/AndroidRuntime(20542):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-22 20:59:14.846: I/Process(20542): Sending signal. PID: 20542 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Would be worthwhile posting the Logcat output

Comment: i have updated my question please have a look! @bdavies6086